# Getting two outcomes from one script

Tags: powershell

```
write-host "Remotely Map to Network Printer"

#$Targets = @( "Computername" )
$Targets = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Computers(Printer 
Before).txt"

$PrintServer =  "\\Server"
$GetPrinter = Get-Printer -ComputerName $PrintServer|select 
Name,PortName,DriverName|Out-GridView -Title "Choose the printer you 
would like to connect to." -PassThru
        $Content = "Add-Printer -ConnectionName 
'$PrintServer\$($GetPrinter.name)'"

ForEach ($TargetPC in $Targets)
{
    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $TargetPC -Quiet -count 1 - 
   ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
        Write-Host "Could not connect to $TargetPC." -ForegroundColor Red}
    else{
        Write-Host "Creating remote task..."
       
        mkdir "\\$ComputerName\C$\Temp" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        
        $results = icm -ComputerName $TargetPC -ArgumentList $Content -ScriptBlock {
            New-Item "C:\Temp\Script.ps1" -Force
            Add-Content "C:\Temp\Script.ps1" $Args[0]
            
            $Path = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint";
            
            New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -name "RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force;
            
            $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
            $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument '-WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Temp\Script.ps1"'
            $Task = New-ScheduledTask -Trigger $Trigger -Action $Action
            
            Register-ScheduledTask Script -InputObject $Task -User "SYSTEM"
            Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName Script
            
            while ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Script").State  -ne 'Ready'){
                Write-Host "Waiting on task execution..."
                Sleep 5
            }
            
            Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName Script -Confirm:$False
            New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -name "RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force;
            rm "C:\Temp\Script.ps1"
            (Get-PrinterDriver).name
            }
    }
    if($Results -eq "$($GetPrinter.DriverName)"){
        Write-Host "Printer driver installed on $TargetPC." -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Output "$TargetPC" | Out-File -filepath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mapped Computers.txt" -Append}
        else{
            Write-host "Driver installation unsuccessful. Recommend manually installing driver." -ForegroundColor Red 
            Write-Output "$TargetPC" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Failed Computers.txt" -Append}
}
```

After running the script, it's just supposed to give me two different outputs. If I can't connect to the computer then it will output the "Could not connect to $TargetPC". If the computer was able to have the driver installed on it then it would give me the "Printer driver installed on $TargetPC"

But what I am getting is that when the script fails to connect to the computer, then I get both
Could not connect to $TargetPC
Printer driver installed on $TargetPC

It then moves to the next computer in the list.

How do I stop the script from giving me both outcomes

Comment: If your ```Test-Connection``` **succeeds** on Printer 1 you follow the ```else``` branch and  set ```$results = icm -ComputerName $TargetPC ... etc ...```. If your ```Test-Connection``` then **fails** on Printer 2, ```$Results``` still contains the results from Printer 1 so ```if($Results -eq "$($GetPrinter.DriverName)"){``` is still ```$true``` from Printer 1. You need to set ```$Results = $null``` at the start of your ```foreach``` to reset the variable at the start of each iteration...